# how to find elements of a numeric array that are greater than the elements in front of them

Tags: javascript, arrays

`array: const data = [158,164,742,99,155,250,240,87]`

It is necessary to output to the console numbers that are greater than the previous ones:
`console.log(164 742 155 250)`

```js
const data = [158, 164, 742, 99, 155, 250, 240, 87]
function biggerElement(data) {
  for (let i = 1; i < -1; i++) {
    if (data[i] > data[i - 1]) console.log(data[i])
  }
}
```

how to solve this task?
thanks

Comment: Show us what have you done so far and where are you stuck or what error message are you getting?

Comment: const data = [158,164,742,99,155,250,240,87]

function biggerElement(data)
{
    
    for (let i = 1; i < -1; i++) {
        if (data[i] > data[i - 1] )
       console.log(data[i]) 
    }
}

Comment: Your for loop starts at 1 and goes up, but the stop condition says to run while i < -1, which is never true, so your loop never executes. You want to run while i < data.length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array filter method runs a function for each element in an array, and returns only the elements for which the function returns true. It receives the index of the current element. So you can access the previous element in your filter callback.

```
data.filter((value, i) => i > 0 && value > data[i - 1])
```

`filter` also receives the original array as the third argument, so you could use that instead of accessing `data` directly if that matters for your case, like if you wanted to make this helper reusable:

```js
const biggerThanPrevious = (value, i, array) => i > 0 && value > array[i - 1]
// ... then somewhere else
const data = [158,164,742,99,155,250,240,87]
console.log(data.filter(biggerThanPrevious))
```

Comment: This would be a better answer with a working example (perhaps as a snippet) using the example array from the OP's question

Comment: Done, I didn't know about snippets.

Comment: You just need `x > a[i - 1]` You don't need `i > 0 &&` because `.filter()` does not return falsey data like `undefined` or empty strings ''.

Comment: This isn't code golf and I would rather make the i > 0 check explicit than depend on the fact that `i > undefined` is both not an error and is always false, because JS likes to sometimes do some weird coercion that can especially confuse newcomers. And besides, it has nothing to do with filter returning undefined since filter returns the values in the array, not what your callback returns. `i > undefined` is still boolean, it's just not obvious to everyone what that will do.

Answer (score 3):

Use `.flatMap()` and compare current with future values:

```
x < a[i+1] ? a[i+1] : []
```

It has come to my attention that there's very little use for `.flatMap()` as a filter.

Then why not use `.map()` since `.flatMap()` is essentially the same thing but with one extra step? That extra step allows me to think a straight forward logic in which I can use simpler algorithms and not have to worry about the common side affects when dealing with arrays like getting empties. Here's a version of example #1 vs. a version using `.map()`.

```js
const data = [158, 164, 742, 99, 155, 250, 240, 87];

let resA = data.flatMap((x, i, a) => x < a[i + 1] ? a[i + 1] : []);

console.log(resA);

let resB = data.map((x, i, a) => x < a[i + 1] ? a[i + 1] : '');

console.log(resB);
```

So both `.map()` and `.flatMap()` are required to return after every iteration, but because `.flatMap()` has a built-in `.flat()` method, you can return an empty array which becomes nothing which is better than an empty like '', or `undefined`.

How about `.filter()` which of course is the most obvious answer? Compare [Vectorjohn's callback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71132646/2813224), vs. my callback:

```
i > 0 && x > a[i - 1] // Vectorjohn, using .filter()

x < a[i + 1] ? a[i + 1] : [] // Me, using .flatMap()
```

Using `.filter()` you actually have no need to worry about blowing past zero and returning `undefined` because `.filter()` never returns falsey data only truthy data. So his callback can simply be the backwards version of my callback by removing `i > 0 &&`:

```
x > a[i - 1] // .filter() will return x

x < a[i + 1] ? a[i + 1] : [] // .flatMap() will return a[i + 1]
```

My callback doesn't eliminate undefined automatically so amittedly it is more verbose than Vj's callback (once I corrected it). ***But***, `.flatMap()` can do far more than `.filter()`. While `.filter()` always returns the current value (`x`) on each iteration, `.flatMap()` can return anything (`a[i + 1]`), multiple anythings (`["any", x]`), or nothing (`[]`) on each iteration.

### Example 1

```js
const data = [158, 164, 742, 99, 155, 250, 240, 87];

let res = data.flatMap((x, i, a) => x < a[i + 1] ? a[i + 1] : []);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Recommend an update to: "Use `.flarMap()` and " unless you meant something else?

Comment: Hah! Tharrrnks!

Comment: Flatmaps seems needlessly confusing. Conceptually the operation they are doing is filtering elements out of the array. Given the nature of the question, I would expect an explanation of what flatmap is would help. You're returning an array of arrays, and then the nested arrays are flattened.

Comment: For some reason I feel more comfortable using ternaries this way, as a plus chaining (or is it nesting?) ternaries makes this method very flexible.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [158, 164, 742, 99, 155, 250, 240, 87]

let numbers_to_print = ''

data.forEach(number => {
  const index = data.indexOf(number)

  if (number > data[index - 1]) {
    numbers_to_print += `${number} `
    // you can also just console.log(number), but I like to use a string
  } 
})

console.log(numbers_to_print)
```

Comment: Don't use map if you're not returning a value. map returns a new array consisting of the values returned from the callback. Also don't make a string list of numbers to print without spaces. Just use an array.

Comment: Yeah, I could use an array for printing, but I like more how string looks like :). And about map you're right, I should use forEach intead @Vectorjohn

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it with your forloop.

**NOTE**: Never use a minus or negative value in your loops unless the conditions requires you iterating your loop backwards.

```js
const data = [158, 164, 742, 99, 155, 250, 240, 87];
var result = [];
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  if(data[i] > data[i - 1]){
    result.push(data[i]);
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a good application for Array.prototype.reduce().

Let the 2nd parameter of the reduce function (the accumulator/carry value) be an object with two keys representing the resulting array and the previous iteration's value.

```js
let data = [158, 164, 742, 99, 155, 250, 240, 87];

let result = data.reduce(function(accumulator, currValue) {
  if (currValue > accumulator.lastValue) {
    accumulator.greaterThanPrev.push(currValue);
  }
  accumulator.lastValue = currValue;
  return accumulator;

}, {
  greaterThanPrev: [],
  lastValue: 4294967295 // BACK-COMPAT. MAX INT.
});

console.log(result.greaterThanPrev)
```

Then for each iteration, test the current iteration's value against the 'lastValue' in the object being passed through the iterations of the reduce function.  If it's greater, push it onto the 'greaterThanPrev' array and update the 'lastValue' key-value.  Then return that object for the next iteration to work against.  When the reduce function is done, it will return the ending object and the 'greaterThanPrev' will contain all of the desired values.

I'm certain someone else could think of a cleaner approach, but this came to mind rather quickly.

Comment: This would be a better answer with a working example (perhaps as a snippet) using the example array from the OP's question

Comment: That was my after-thought, too.   Just added the improved coding example.

Comment: I did however make a snippet of your code and took liberty to add a console.log() feel free to override what I did.

Comment: I downvoted because I think reduce for this problem is over-engineering to the point of obfuscation, and depends on some (imo) inelegant tricks like choosing a big number for lastValue (how about actually use max int, NaN, or even better an explicit flag?)
But if a downvote isn't appropriate for this kind of critique I'm happy to remove it. I don't know the customs around these parts :)

Comment: @Vectorjohn, thanks for the explanation.
I chose this inelegant trick for `lastValue`'s initial value because it's simple, explicit and backwards compatible with all browsers (unlike Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER).  I never considered NaN, because that's a nonsensical comparison to make against a number, even if JS handles it in a way that technically works.  I'll take your critique and downvote, but I personally feel like the flatMap solution is 10x more ambiguous than my answer, which doesn't require nearly as many array accesses or calculations, it simply passes the necessary state-data along.

Comment: @TroyNiemeier Hey, I don't like the flatMap one either, but I'm advocating my own version simply using filter :) 
And to be clear, NaN would never be compared to a number, you'd have an explicit check that this is the first iteration. I don't think it's great but not really any worse than a magic number imo. What about Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY ? 
Anyway, I just think there is a lot more going on and room for error in this version. I think the complexity hides what the function is actually doing.